# Getting the user in Cognito does not work while you have all the rights

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, .net-core-2.0

When I try to get a user in a lambda on Amazon Web Services:

```
var client = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient();
var user = await client.GetUserAsync(new GetUserRequest { AccessToken = request.AccessToken });
```

I get error:

> Cannot determine protocol

Lambda is published with the role to which AmazonCognitoPowerUser policy is attached.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cognito-identity:*",
                "cognito-idp:*",
                "cognito-sync:*",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "iam:ListOpenIdConnectProviders",
                "sns:ListPlatformApplications"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Pattern `cognito-idp:*` permits to take any action, in particular, the creation and deletion of users happens without problems. Only getting doesn't work.

To the role additionally gave admin rights - full access to everything. Useless. How could that be?

There are many tips in Internet to create a provider with anonymous permissions:

```
new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(new AnonymousAWSCredentials())
```

then the receiving user is works. But not working create/delete user, which is natural.

With an explicit setting of the keys (accessKey, secretKey) getting the user also works.

Q: how do I get a user from under a specific role without having to set parameters directly?

Comment: I am experiencing this problem too. Works fine on my local machine with credentials in `.aws/credentials`. When I deploy to my docker container in elastic beanstalk I get the same error with similar policy attached